# Рейтинг пользователей по баллам

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как, в MySql реализовать рейтинг пользователей по баллам:
Есть таблица, `table(user_id, score)`.
Известен id пользователя, нужно узнать на каком он месте среди всех других при сортировке по баллам (`score`).
Нужен пример.

Comment: Я вам в комментариях к такому же вчерашнему вопросу практически готовое решение давал, там надо было только вместо X подставить получение score конкретного пользователя. Так что напишите, что вы уже сами пробовали сделать для решения задачи

Comment: Хотя, конечно, надо еще решить, что сделать с пользователями у которых score одинаковый, кого из них считать ближе к началу рейтинга

Comment: @Mike а он/она хитропопый. Он удалил его https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699402/191482  34 минуты назад https://i.stack.imgur.com/mouEp.jpg

Comment: Вообще я так прикидываю, быстрый расчет это нетривиальная задача. Часто ее решают просто перечитывая позицию по всем раз в час например и храня результат расчета. Если надо в режиме онлайн, то надо исходить из конкретной специфики, как часто меняется score, на какие величины, как часто идут запросы на текущий рейтинг, каков процент тех, рейтинг которых надо где то отображать за единицу времени, каков % тех у кого вообще меняется рейтинг. Так что для действительно правильного ответа потребуется знать вашу систему целиком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так

```
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS position, your_table.*
FROM your_table, (select @i:=0) AS z
ORDER BY score DESC;
```